# SQL Create formula variables in a view

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I need help generating formulas from values from separate tables to create 
    new variables in a view.

Here are examples of some of the variables I must create with their 
    formulas:

```
(partpos)= number of P+ divided by #intervals times 100
(partneg)= number of P- divided by #intervals times 100
(nocodeview)= number of N√ divided by #intervals times 100
(nocodeint) = number of N● divided by #intervals times 100
```

Could someone go over how I could create a view with the `partpos`, `partneg`, 
etc. variables as columns with rows listed by observation ID. For example, 
looking at the first variable to create, there are 5 intervals in the first 
observation and 2 of these have value of `p`+. So how can I count both and 
then divide # of intervals by # of `p+` to get the `partpos` value for each 
observation id?

Here is the database structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkqgX.png

Comment: That image link doesn't work.